# windows server (dns): give a name to a local site

Tags: windows, networking, dns

In my intention, I have to give a name to a local site identified by a private ip.

My dns server is provided by Windows server 2003.

I know how to create a record to a specific web server, for example

```
192.168.1.1           -     mySite.local
```

but i can't realize how to set up a record to a site that is hosted on my private web server, for example:

```
192.168.1.1/mySite    -     mySite.local
```

I image that it is a simple situation, but I can't solve it!

Answer (score 0):

DNS only translates computer names to IPs. To get "mySite.local" to serve "192.168.1.1/mySite" you need to configure your web server. In Apache, this is usually the `DocumentRoot` configuration item within a `VirtualHost` stanza. I'm not sure how you ould go about configuring IIS for this if you're serving from IIS in Windows.